# Updating one table (MySQL) based on certain conditions related to another table

Tags: mysql, database, datatables

The question is :
"Increase the fare of airlines by 10% for Delhi to Mumbai flights"

I know that one way is to check the corresponding flight no myself and use that in the query but I want the query to be in terms of the columns given in the table only.I tried the following which both failed:
1)update fares set fare=1.1*fare where flights.start='Delhi' and flights.end='Mumbai';

2)update fares set fare=1.1*fare where (flights natural join fares).start='Delhi' and (flights natural join fares).end='Mumbai';

Please help

The flights table has columns flight no,start,end,noofflights,noofstops

Fares table has flightno,fare,airlines,taxrate

Comment: What didn't work ?

Comment: It was giving me an error(can't see a syntax error myself)

Comment: It said unknown column flights.start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's what you want :

```
Update fares fs
LEFT JOIN flight f on f.flightno = fs.flightno
SET fare = 1.1 * fare
WHERE f.start='Delhi' and f.end='Mumbai';
```

Comment: Why use left join?

Comment: my mistake, no need of left join, you can use an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

Below SQL might help you for ref

```
UPDATE FLIGHT FL INNER JOIN FARES FR 
ON FL.flightno = FR.flightno SET FR.fare = (1.1 * FR.FR) 
WHERE FL.start = 'Delhi' AND FL.end = 'Mumbai' ;
```